# React Warning: findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode

Tags: reactjs, warnings, reactcsstransitiongroup

I´m trying to use CSSTransition group but receiving the warning 'Warning: findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode.'. I´ve been seraching for different threads on internet but non of them useful, or at least not sure how to implement them. Any ideas on how to ref the code??

```
<TransitionGroup>
 {tareasproyecto.map((tarea) => (
  <CSSTransition key={tarea.id} timeout={300} classNames="tarea">
    <Tarea tarea={tarea} />
  </CSSTransition>
))}
</TransitionGroup>
```

Below this is the error I'm receiving

```
Warning: findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode. findDOMNode was passed an instance of Transition which is inside StrictMode. Instead, add a ref directly to the element you want to reference. Learn more about using refs safely here
```

Thanks!!